# Hide submenu icons in jQuery UI Menu Widget

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to hide the submenu icon for jquery ui menu widget (default value is *ui-icon-carat-1-e*).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
        $( "#menu" ).menu({
            icons: { 
                submenu: false
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I guess the solution is very simple, but I can't get it :-(

Thanks for your help, guys.

EDIT: Here's my html code:

```
<ul id="menu" style="z-index:1">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" style="margin: 3px 0 0 4px;"></span>Information </a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="?site=something"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-star" style="margin: 2px 0 0 4px;"></span>Something</a></li>
            <li>...</li>
...
        </ul>
    </ul>
```

And here's the code when jquery has done it's hob:

```
<ul id="menu" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-menu-icons" style="z-index:1" role="menu" tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-152">
    <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
        <a id="ui-id-152" class="ui-corner-all" href="#" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
            <span class="ui-menu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-e"></span>
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" style="margin: 3px 0 0 4px;"></span>
                Information 
        </a>
        <ul class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="display: none; top: 31px; left: 20px;" role="menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true">
            <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"> … </li>
            <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"> … </li>
            <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"> … </li>
            <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"> … </li>
```

And I want to remove this annoying span tag **span class="ui-menu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-e"**

Cheers
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Working Fiddle using jquery solution](http://jsfiddle.net/vn73m/4/)

Basically you can do this by using the jquery remove command.

**JS(run after initializing the widget)**

```
$('.ui-menu-icon.ui-icon.ui-icon-carat-1-e').remove();
```

Comment: Hi, this does not work. When I take a look at the generated source code, it looks like this: `<ul id="menu" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-menu-icons" role="menu" tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-151"><li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-151" class="ui-corner-all" href="#" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><span class="ui-menu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-e"></span> ...` There is no background image at all. jQuery adds the <span> tag... after all, I could create an "empty" icon and tell jQuery to use this instead.

Comment: @DaFunkyAlex its working in both of those js fiddles unless I misunderstood your question?  Did u mean you wanted the top level menus icon removed as well?

Comment: Hey Rooster, I've updated my question above, maybe it's a bit more clear what I want to do, thanks you

Comment: okay, that's it! thx. `$(document).ready(function(){
  $(function() {
   $( "#menu" ).menu({
    position: {
     my:'left top',
     at:'left bottom'
    }
   });
        
   $('.ui-menu-icon.ui-icon.ui-icon-carat-1-e').remove();
   
  });
    
 });`

Answer (score 4):

The previous answer is a poor hack.
You can use the proper settings to remove the icon, tho this will leave an empty space where the icon would normally go.
Use CSS to remove the extra spacing for the icon.  You can do both, or just the CSS part.

Javascript menu initialization (optional change - css will hide it fully):

```
$("#mymenu").menu({
    icons: {submenu: 'ui-icon-blank'}
});
```

CSS changes:

```
#mymenu .ui-menu-icon{display: none;}
#mymenu.ui-menu .ui-menu-item{padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;}
```